# Как менять значение лейбла?

Tags: java

Задача: Напишите программу, при запуске которой создается и выводится на экран графическое окно. В окне размещена группа компонентов JRadioButton, метка и кнопка. После нажатия на кнопку, текст выбранной радиокнопки отображается в тексте метки.

Добился пока что только такого результата. Не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы значение лейбла менялось?

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Main {
    JFrame frame;
    String a = ("Нажмите на кнопку ниже и надпись тут изменится");
    String b = ("1");
    String c = ("2");
    String d = ("3");

    Main()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();

        JLabel label = new JLabel(a, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setBounds(20,0,400,80);

        JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton(b);
        JRadioButton btn2 = new JRadioButton(c);
        JRadioButton btn3 = new JRadioButton(d);

        btn1.setBounds(40,60,200,50);
        btn2.setBounds(40,100,200,50);
        btn3.setBounds(40,140,200,50);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(btn1);
        bg.add(btn2);
        bg.add(btn3);

        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(btn1);
        frame.add(btn2);
        frame.add(btn3);

        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();

    }
}
```

Comment: Теперь необходимо повесить обработчик, который будет вызываться при изменении. Посмотри, здесь имеется довольно хорошее описание с примером: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jradiobutton

Comment: @kio
Добавил вот такое условие, но надпись по прежнему не меняется, что делать?
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(btn1.isSelected()){
                    a = b;
                }
                if(btn2.isSelected()){
                    a = c;
                }
                if(btn3.isSelected()){
                    a = d;
                }
            }

Comment: У тебя такое скомпилировалось без ошибок? 
Ты пытаешься сравнивать строки, поэму и не меняться.

Comment: @kio
Компилируется без ошибок, но изменений никаких не происходит

Comment: В таком коде ты в строку А присваиваешь строку B. Используй label.setText(labelText) labelText- твоя строка

Comment: @kio
Если вы говорите о подобном методе, то почему то по прежнему ничего не меняется.
if(btn1.isSelected()){
                    label.setText(b);
                }

Comment: А обработчик повесил на объект? Типа такого -  btn1.addActionListener(this);

Comment: @kio
Все заработало, спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JRadioButton btn1, btn2, btn3;
    JLabel label;
    String a = ("Нажмите на кнопку ниже и надпись тут изменится");
    String b = ("1");
    String c = ("2");
    String d = ("3");
    Main()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();

        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText(a);
        label.setBounds(20,0,400,80);

        btn1 = new JRadioButton(b);
        btn2 = new JRadioButton(c);
        btn3 = new JRadioButton(d);

        btn1.setBounds(40,60,200,50);
        btn2.setBounds(40,100,200,50);
        btn3.setBounds(40,140,200,50);


        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(btn1);
        bg.add(btn2);
        bg.add(btn3);

        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(btn1);
        frame.add(btn2);
        frame.add(btn3);

        frame.setSize(500,300);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);
    }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(btn1.isSelected()){
                    label.setText(b);
                }
                if(btn2.isSelected()){
                    label.setText(c);
                }
                if(btn3.isSelected()){
                    label.setText(d);
                }
            }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).